# Repeat extracting values from all rasters in a folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, iterator

I want to extract values from multiple .tif files in one folder to points, which means I repeat extracting values from multiple TIFF rasters many times. How can I do this using an iterator? I prefer ModelBuilder to Python codes.

Comment: Extract multivalues to points will do it in one go. No model or script required.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Iterate Rasters iterator](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-rasters.htm):

Iterates over rasters in a Workspace or a Raster Catalog (I dont have Spatial Analyst so I use Project Raster to show the logic):

[image]

Comment: No, I want to extract them separately instead of getting a subset from tif rasters.

Comment: They are iterated separetly

Comment: But the output is one raster. I have used this method and I extracted values from only one tif raster. Is there something wrong or I did not use it correctly?

Comment: It should work for multiple rasters. How do you name the output so you arent overwriting the output for each iteration and ending up with only one? Look at how I use the %Name% to use each input raster to name the output

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your answer.